# Matching filenames with regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking for a regex command to match file names in a folder. I already got all the filenames in a list. Now I want to match a pattern in a loop (file is the string to match):

```
./test1_word1_1.1_1.2_1.3.csv
```

with:

```
match = re.search(r'./{([\w]+)}_word1_{([0-9.]+)}_{([0-9.]+)}_{([0-9.]+)}*',file)
```

I used to get regex working but in this special case it simple doesn't work. Can you help me with that?

I want to continue with the match of regex the following way (I've written the outcome here):

```
match[0] = test1
match[1] = 1.1
match[2] = 1.2
match[3] = 1.3
```

The curly brackets are my fault. They don't make sense at all. Sorry

Best regards,
sebastian

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Please post the error message, or the desired and incorrect output.

Comment: Try [`\./([^\W_]+)_word1_([0-9.]+)_([0-9.]+)_([0-9.]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/fOr9st/1). What are the curly braces for in your pattern? The braces are meaningful, and are treated as literal symbols in the pattern. Also, `\w` matches `_`, too, thus, replace `\w` with `[^\W_]` - not sure it is what you need. What are the rules for matching filenames?

Comment: The problem is, that I got a none as match, so the pattern is not recognized by regex.
    print match >>> None 
I want to continue using the expressions from the file name. My desired output is: 
    match[0] = test1
    match[1] = 1.1
    match[2] = 1.2
    match[3] = 1.3

Comment: Please specify the rules for file name matching and the expected output for the example string.

Comment: I just annoted the question to make clear what I expect as an output. The curly brackets are indeed complete senseless

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, seems like capture groups were needed, I deleted your answer is more valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
r'\./([^\W_]+)_word1_([0-9.]+)_([0-9.]+)_([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)*)'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fOr9st/3)

**Details**:

- `\.` - a literal dot (if it is unescaped it matches any char other than a line break char)
- `/` - a `/` symbol (no need escaping it in a Python regex pattern)
- `([^\W_]+)` - Group 1 matching 1 or more letters or  digits (if you want to match a chunk containing `_`, keep your original `(\w+)` pattern)
- `_word1_`  - a literal substring
- `([0-9.]+)` - Group 1 matching 1 or more digits and/or `.` symbols
- `_` - an underscore
- `([0-9.]+)` - Group 2 matching 1 or more digits and/or `.` symbols
- `_` - an underscore
- `([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)*)` - Group 3 matching 1 or more digits, then 0+ sequences of a `.` and 1 or more digits

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/4Ogblg):

```
import re
rx = r"\./([^\W_]+)_word1_([0-9.]+)_([0-9.]+)_([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)*)"
s = "./test1_word1_1.1_1.2_1.3.csv"
m = re.search(rx, s)
if m:
    print("Part1: {}\nPart2: {}\nPart3: {}\nPart4: {}".format(m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3), m.group(4) ))
```

Output:

```
Part1: test1
Part2: 1.1
Part3: 1.2
Part4: 1.3
```

Comment: Thank you very much. There is now an existing matching object. I still can't access it but I will try to work in that in my own! 
    `TypeError: '_sre.SRE_Match' object is not callable`

Comment: I will add a snippet

Comment: @sebastian I had to adjust the regex to capture the last group without a trailing `.`, fixed the explanation and added a snippet.

Comment: @Wiktir Stribiżew: I accepted the answer. I didn't want to bother you with the extra dot, so I decided to cut the match off at this point. I'm glad there is another way as well! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Since test_word<>.csv is the file name and content inside <> will always changing and are dot delimited numbers,  Can you try this?

r"test1_word[_0-9.]*.csv"g

Sample code and test strings

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"test1_word[_0-9.]*.csv"

test_str = ("./test1_word1_1.1_1.2_1.3.csv\n"
    "./test1_word1_1.31.2_1.555.csv\n"
    "./test1_word1_10.31.2_2000.00.csv")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
    matchNum = matchNum + 1

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

Want to test? https://regex101.com/ will help you.

Comment: However, I presume, you got the answer from "Wiktor Stribiżew" already.

Comment: I made same mistake, you don't capture the different numbers as group this way. Hence the need for multiple capture groups